# プログラムから操作できる、相関図を作るツールを探しています

Tags: ruby

現在、RubyからDBのデータを元に人物の相関図を作りたいと考えているのですが、良いツールが見つからなくて困っています。

この相関図に求める機能としては、「絵＋名前で要素を表現したい」「人物の数が100以上なので、全体的に見た時に横長ではなく正方形で表示したい」「要素を結ぶ線をある程度カスタマイズできるといい」です。

私が調べた限りでは、これらの要素を満たすものとしては[blockdiag](http://blockdiag.com/ja/blockdiag/examples.html#simple-diagram-for-master-data-manager)です。ただ問題点としてはこのツールは相関図を書くプログラムではないため、うまく正方形にするには、要素数を計算して上手くグループして縦、横に並べるプログラムを書く必要性がありそうな点です。

そこで質問なのですが、相関図をプログラムからないしはCUIから書けるツールをごぞんではないでしょうか？ご回答宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: @sakuroさんの言及しているツールの１つでGvizと言うのを、作者が詳細に解説してます。[Gvizの目次 - Rubyの世界からGraphvizの世界にこんにちは！](http://melborne.github.io/2014/02/27/gviz-posts/) その中で [Graphvizで作る国旗の類似度世界地図](http://melborne.github.io/2013/04/23/map-of-national-flags-with-graphviz/) が求める例に近いのでは？

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。こちらのDotとGraphvizを使えば描画できそうです。勉強して見ます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

この手の図は(graphvizなどが採用している)dot言語で書くのが定番だと思います。Rubyで書いたDSLからdotに変換するツールもいくつかあるようなので、試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

dot言語自体は、

- ノードやエッジの形状はカスタマイズ可能。
- 画像の出力はノードにimageを指定することで可能。
- 正方形への出力は、size で出力サイズ(インチ)を1つ(縦と横に共用する=正方形)指定の上、 [ratio](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#a:ratio) に fill を指定すれば、指定サイズいっぱいにひろがるようノード間隔を調整する機能があるようです。

とりあえずsize指定に加えて `ratio = fill` がない場合とある場合の比較をしてみましたが、もともとある程度正方形に近かったので、若干引き伸ばされた程度の差しか出ず、分かりにくいかもしれません。

[image: ratioなし]

[image: ratioあり]

Comment: Dot形式というものがあるのですね。ありがとうございます、こちらで実装していきます。